# How to configure a VM from HyperV host using Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a HyperV server with over 10 VMs hosted on it. They all use a base image so they are not connected to a domain nor do they have there NIC configured. Is there a way that I could run commands from the host to configure the VMs NIC and join the domain as if I was actually logged in?

This is easily done if I just pop open the VM from HyperV:

```
###Joining domain###

$domain = "mydomain.gbl"
$cred = get-credential mydomain\defaultuser

Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred
```

Now this approach is ok if I had only a few machines but since I have so many and even more machines to come that need configuration, I am trying to find a way to automate these tasks.

Maybe I could create a scheduled task on the VMs from the host?

Comment: Are you using SCVMM or plain Hyper-V?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that we are using SCVMM as well. This is news to me

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Server 2008 your only option (AFAICS) would be to configure the network interfaces of the VMs with static MAC addresses (e.g. with the [PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/)), set up a DHCP to provide the VMs with IP addresses. After that you should be able to do something e.g. with [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) if the Windows Firewall is disabled on the VMs. If it isn't, you'll have to log in manually. You need at least some basic configuration for remote management.